# mongoose conditional required based on request type

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Can I have a field in a schema like "_id' where its only required if the request type is 'PUT'?

```
const sampleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "Sample _id is required"]
  }
})
```

Comment: If the built-in validators aren't enough, you can define custom validators to suit your needs. Custom validation is declared by passing a validation function: [Custom Validators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators).

Answer (score 0):

If the built-in validators aren't enough, you can define custom validators to suit your needs. Custom validation is declared by passing a validation function - [Custom Validators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const sampleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Number,
    required: function () {
      return !!this._id;
    },
    message: "Sample _id is required"
  }
});

const SampleModel = mongoose.model('Sample', sampleSchema);
```

In Mongoose, an automatically generated `_id` is assigned to each document by default if you don't explicitly set it. Therefore, you don't need to set the `_id` field explicitly when creating a new document unless you want to use a custom `_id`. But note that without an id, mongoose doesn’t allow to save or create a new document - [Ids](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id).